# Google Maps Circle center on screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I have painted a Circle in my Google Maps map like this:

```
    var circle = CircleOptions().center(googleMap?.cameraPosition?.target)
            .radius(MAX_RADIUS.toDouble())
            .fillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.mapCircle))
            .strokeWidth(0f)
    Timber.w("Painting circle!")
    staticCircle = googleMap?.addCircle(circle)
```

Now I want to keep this circle centered in the map, so I did this:

```
 googleMap?.setOnCameraMoveListener {
            var center = googleMap?.cameraPosition?.target

            if (center != null) {
                Timber.v("Centering circle in $center")
                animatedCircle?.center = center
                staticCircle?.center = center
            }
        }
```

However movement is jerky and also when auto zooming is happening the circle is moving with the camera instead of waiting for it to settle in.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't add circle to the map fragment if the purpose is just to show the center of the map. You can instead overlay circle on map fragment.

Comment: the circle defines the radius of search within the map, so it needs to be part of the map (in order for me to define the radius in meters, and for the markers to show above it)

Comment: I also experienced that jerkiness, luckily had to show the center only. Maybe use a handler with some delay(~50-100ms) so that it doesn't get called numerous times and cancel previous calls in between.

Answer (score 0):

How about using *setOnCameraIdleListener* instead of *setOnCameraMoveListener*? Callback will be fired only when movement of camera / zoom has ended

Comment: mmm but then it would not move as the user pans, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)-based [custom view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) with overridden ['dispatchDraw()'](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) (because `MapView` is `ViewGroup`) that draw circle over its content. And circle radius should be recalculated for current zoom level. Something like that:

```
public class CustomMapView extends MapView implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private OnMapReadyCallback mMapReadyCallback;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private int mRadiusInMeters = 500;
    private Paint mPaintCircle;

    public CustomMapView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public CustomMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable GoogleMapOptions options) {
        super(context, options);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        drawCircle(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        VisibleRegion visibleRegion = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
        LatLngBounds screenBounds = visibleRegion.latLngBounds;
        LatLng mapCenter = screenBounds.getCenter();
        final Point pointMapCenter = mGoogleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(mapCenter);
        final double meters_int_pixel = (Math.cos(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude * Math.PI /180) * 2 * Math.PI * 6378137)
                / (256 * Math.pow(2, mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));
        final int radius = (int)(mRadiusInMeters / meters_int_pixel);
        canvas.drawCircle(pointMapCenter.x, pointMapCenter.y, radius, mPaintCircle);
    }

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        mPaintCircle = new Paint();
        mPaintCircle.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaintCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintCircle.setAlpha(90);
        mPaintCircle.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    @Override
    public void getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
        mMapReadyCallback = callback;
        super.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        if (mMapReadyCallback != null) {
            mMapReadyCallback.onMapReady(googleMap);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use that custom view in your `MainActivity` that way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";
    private CustomMapView mMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        mMapView = (CustomMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }

        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

with layout file `activity_main.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.test.just.googlemapsgeneral.views.CustomMapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```